# Read the word document content from google drive

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying fetch doc content from google drive using the Google sdk. The problem is, the `get()` function is not working properly. It gives only file metadata not any actual content.

```
$googl = new Googl(); 
$this->client = $googl->client();
$this->client->setAccessToken(session('user.token'));
$this->drive = $googl->drive($this->client);

$file = $this->drive->files->get("fileId"); 
return $file;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) it looks like you can download a file using:

```
$file = $this->drive->files->get("fileId", array('alt' => 'media'));
$content = $file->getBody()->getContents();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that we may have a language issue here.

**Read the content from a Google drive file**

The google drive api is a file datastore api.  This means that it stores the file itself and the information about said file.  It does not give you any access to the contents of that file.

If you want to know what is in the file you will need to download the file and open it up on your machine.

or try [Google documents api](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/) however i suspect that it will only be able to read a google drive document file and not a word file you may have to convert it first.

**download the the file**

If you check the documentation for [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) you will find the following.

```
 $fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
$response = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
    'alt' => 'media'));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```